# Iterating String Array by a specific value

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I'm iterating over an ArrayList with String arrays inside.

```
["A","1"]
["A","2"]
["A","3"]
["B","1"]
["B","2"]
["B","3"]
```

How can I select only the ones with an "A" on the first position? Without iterating, and saving on a new array...

```
for (String[] key : keys){  
}
```

Using a for each for example, what I want is, for the first iteration -> only work with the String Arrays with "A", second iteration -> only work with the String Arrays with "B".

Comment: Guava has tools for doing things like this, but really, it seems like you want a multimap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    String[][] keys = {
        {"A","1"},
        {"A","2"},
        {"A","3"},
        {"B","1"},
        {"B","2"},
        {"B","3"},
    };
    String[][] result = Stream.of(keys)
        .filter(x -> x[0].equals("A"))
        .toArray(String[][]::new);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a solution with Java 8?

```
List<String[]> result = keys.stream()
                            .filter(t -> "A".equals(t[0]))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Can i use Java 8 in JSP?

Comment: *Yup*. It depends on the application server. Are you using Tomcat 8 or Wildfly with JDK 8? What app server are you using?

Answer (score -1):

you can´t without going through each one (either iterating or in parallel). But you probably want a Map. Check this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html